# PHP DateTime::createFromFormat AM PM Issue

Tags: php

```
$format = 'd M Y A h:i';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '11 Mar 2013 PM 3:34');
```

Returns false.
getLastErrors returs:

> ```
> [errors] => Array
>     (
>         [12] => Unexpected data found.
>     )
> ```

After removing A in format and PM in date it started to work.

```
$format = 'd M Y h:i';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '11 Mar 2013 3:34');
```

Any solution how to make it working with AM and PM ?

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: In that case, the first thing to do is update to the latest 5.3 revision (currently 5.3.25); if this is a bug in PHP, it may have been fixed in the versions between.

Answer (score 0):

I would append the AM/PM after the time.  See http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php for accepted time formats.

Comment: That's not a solution, that date cames from customers export file.

Comment: @user2455079 - granted this isn't a solution, but it might be worth checking whether it works -- if it works that way but not your way, you may have found a PHP bug (in which case, make sure you're on the latest revision, check again, write a short simple demo program to show the problem, and then report it to the PHP bug tracker)

Comment: It works... but it wouldn't help anyway =)
Maybe some str_replace will help in this situation to move it to end...

Comment: I was under the impression that you could remove AM/PM and thus append it at the end, based on your question saying that you removed it.  I wouldn't say it's a bug, just a feature/format they didn't add.

Comment: DateTime::createFromFormat is used to parse string with any date format using format. Function has support for AM PM parsing, but it doesn't works properly. Removing AM was just for testing. Read createFromFormat documentation before saying that the didn't add something.

Comment: The documentation does not state **any** date, anywhere.  Just because it doesn't parse the way you want it to doesn't mean it's a bug.  I could have a date *12/06/01 5:30p* doesn't mean it needs to work.  Clearly it's PM to me, but the parser doesn't look for that.  Read my link on [accepted time formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php) for what their parser catches.  If it were indicated there and it didn't work as a format, then I would say it's a bug.  Also, I didn't realize you meant only for testing purposes until after I answered the question.