# PHP String to DateTime with AM/PM

Tags: php, datetime

It is posible to convert my string with this format "A H:i m/d/y" to a DateTime in php?

Example string: AM 05:28 07/08/13

This don't work

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('A H:i m/d/y', 'AM 05:28 07/08/13');
```

This works:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i m/d/y', '05:28 07/08/13');

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i m/d/y A', '05:28 07/08/13 AM');
```

Ugly work around:

```
$myDate = 'AM 05:28 07/08/13';
$myDate = substr($myDate, 3, strlen($myDate)-3)." ".substr($myDate, 0, 2);

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i m/d/y A', $myDate);
```

Comment: Looks like the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936979/php-datetimecreatefromformat-am-pm-issue. No other solution was found there, either.

Comment: It's a PHP bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64975

Comment: sadly, a quick search of 'google' leads me to suspect it isn't a popular time conversion. so no algorithms that i can provide links to.

Answer (score 2):

This is a php [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64975). Try to use next function:

```
function createFromFormat($format, $time)
{       
    $is_pm  = (stripos($time, 'PM') !== false);
    $time   = str_replace(array('AM', 'PM'), '', $time);
    $format = str_replace('A', '', $format);

    $date   = DateTime::createFromFormat(trim($format), trim($time));

    if ($is_pm)
    {
        $date->modify('+12 hours');
    }

    return $date;
}


$date = createFromFormat('H:i m/d/y A', '05:28 07/08/13 AM');
var_dump($date->format('d.m.Y H:i')); //  string(16) "08.07.2013 05:28" 

$date = createFromFormat('H:i m/d/y A', '05:28 07/08/13 PM');
var_dump($date->format('d.m.Y H:i')); //  string(16) "08.07.2013 17:28"
```