# Convert string to DateTime in PHP

Tags: php

I have log files contain timestamp format like (02/18(Mon)AM11:08). It is (mm/dd(D)AMHH:ii) format. There is no Year value, but I can get the Year value from its filename.
I want to convert the string into datetime format so I can insert into database as datetime type.
I try this with no success

```
$logdate = '(02/18(Mon)AM11:08)';
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('(mm/dd(D)AMHH:ii)', $logdate);
$datetime = date_format($datetime, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Please help me solve the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: This happens because of a PHP bug : [createFromFormat Error parsing when AM PM not at the end](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64975), similar issue : https://stackoverflow.com/q/16936979/8566549, a possible workaround is to move AM/PM to the end of the time : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23641316/8566549

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), `(mm/dd(D)AMHH:ii)` should be `(m/d(D)Ah:i)`, because

- m = numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros, example 01-12
- d = day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros, example 01-31
- A = ante meridiem and post meridiem, example AM or PM
- h = 12-hour format of an hour with leading zero, example 01-12
- i = minutes with leading zeros, example 00-59

Unfortunately, this code doesn't work:

```
$logdate = '(02/18(Mon)AM11:08)';
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('(m/d(D)Ah:i)', $logdate);
echo date_format($datetime, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Playing around by removing/changing/moving parts, the problem occurs with AM/PM in the middle of string. So, i move it to the end:

```
$logdate = '(02/18(Mon)AM11:08)';
$logdate_moved = preg_replace('/(.*)(AM|PM)(.*)/', '$1$3$2', $logdate); // move AM/PM to the end with regex
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('(m/d(D)h:i)A', $logdate_moved); // don't forget to move A to the end
echo date_format($datetime, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

And it works!